# How to get shortcode to work inside a foreach loop called within a shortcode?

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode

My plugin, [WP Coda Slider](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wp-coda-slider/trunk/wpcodaslider.php?rev=294163), uses a shortcode to `get_posts` and add them to the slider.  If one of the posts contains shortcode the shortcode in that post will not work.

```
$my_wpcodaslider = new wpcodaslider();
class wpcodaslider{

    var $shortcode_name = 'wpcodaslider';
    var $pattern = '<!-- wpcodaslider -->';
    var $posts_content = '';

    function wpcodaslider() {
        add_shortcode( $this->shortcode_name, array( &$this, 'shortcode' ) );
        add_action( 'the_posts', array( &$this, 'wpcodaslider_scripts' ) );
    }

    // insert the shortcode in any page ie: [wpcodaslider id=slidername cat=4 show=3] will show first three post in category with id of 4
    function shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'cat' => null,
            'id'  =>  null,
            'show' => null,
            'args' => null
        ), $atts ) );

        //Make sure there is a query and name
        if (! $cat || ! $id)
            return 'Could not load slider. Mallformed shortcode.';
    $o = '
        <div class="coda-slider-wrapper">
            <div class="coda-slider preload" id="'. $id .'">';

        $posts = get_posts('post_type=post&order=desc&cat= '. $cat . '&numberposts= ' . $show . '');
        foreach($posts as $post){

            $o.=
            '<div class="panel" id="post-' . $post->ID . '">
                <div class="panel-wrapper">
                    <h2 class="title">' . $post->post_title . '</h2>
                    ' . $post->post_content . '
                </div> <!-- .panel-wrapper -->
            </div><!-- .panel #post-$id -->';
        }


        $o.='
                </div><!-- .coda-slider .preload -->
            </div><!-- coda-slider-wrapper -->

            <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                $().ready(function() {
                    $(\'#'. $id .'\').codaSlider({' . $args .'});
                });
    });
            </script>';


        return $o;
    }
```

It also does another foreach loop to check for its shortcode before enqueing the scripts.

```
function wpcodaslider_scripts($posts) {


        if (empty($posts)) return $posts;

        $shortcode_found = false; // use this flag to see if styles and scripts need to be enqueued
        foreach ($posts as $post): {
            if (stripos($post->post_content, 'wpcodaslider')) {
                $shortcode_found = true; //shortcode found so lets load the scripts
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($shortcode_found) {
            //enqueue scripts
            wp_enqueue_script('coda_slider', WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/wp-coda-slider/js/coda.slider.js',
            array('jquery'));

            //enqueue style sheet
            wp_enqueue_style('coda_slider', WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/wp-coda-slider/css/coda-slider-2.0.css');
        }

        return $posts;
    }

}
```

Any ideas on how I can get shortcodes within the posts to work?  I have tested it with the `[gallery]` shortcode and a few others from various plugins.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are echoing raw `post_content` field from object. It isn't what usually gets to front-end. Try:

```
apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content )
```

If you want to run shortcodes alone (without bunch of other filters) you can do:

```
do_shortcode( $post->post_content )
```

**Edit** re-read your question... Is there a possibility that this thing gets recursive? Post containing slider shortocde that calls itself?

Comment: I haven't tried it on a post.  All the testing was done with the shortcode added to a page and including posts within a category id.

Answer (score 0):

Rarst is correct, using do_shortcode() will do the trick.  Not sure about apply_filters(), but probably.

If there is an issue with recursion, just de-register your shortcode before the loop and re-register it afterward so that your shortcode won't get evaluated by do_shortcode() in the loop.
(Or just hack up the content you pass to do_shortcode to delete text matching /[wpcodaslider.*]/ - note [ and ] need to be escaped in regexes)