# shortcode inside post called by ID does not render as expected

Tags: functions, shortcode, footer

Hallo i get a post in the theme like this:

```
$footer_post = get_post(pll_get_post(620));
echo $footer_post->post_content; // Load contents of the page
```

That shows the content of post(620) in the footer.

in the functions.php i have:

```
function year_shortcode() {
$year = date('Y');
return $year;}
add_shortcode('YEAR', 'year_shortcode');
```

The problem is, when i write [YEAR] and try to use the shorcode in that specific post, it will render like [YEAR] instead of 2019. Is this a bug or do i have to make a change to my code? When i use the shortcode in a normal site, it renders properly.

WordPress 5.2.4 latest.

Answer (score 2):

See this answer: [How to get shortcode to work inside a foreach loop called within a shortcode?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2273/how-to-get-shortcode-to-work-inside-a-foreach-loop-called-within-a-shortcode)

You'll likely want `apply_filters( 'the_content', $footer_post->post_content )`

And so, in your case:

```
$footer_content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $footer_post->post_content );
echo $footer_content;
```

Comment: Many thanks, that worked immediately...such a weird issue...